# drop down list send values through AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm new to AJAX and trying to learn basic calls through AJAX and jQuery.
I have a simple drop list of countries, where I want to select a particular country and send the value of it to server, where it would process which country was selected and give particular output. For now, it could just echo simple output in php file. There is some kind of problem with this code. I would appreciate if anyone could help me with it. thanks

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function load()
 {
      $.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      url: "test.php",
      data: { country: $("#country").val()}
      }).done(function(msg){
       $("#right #myDiv").html(msg);
      });
 }

 </script>
 </head>
 <body>

 <div id="main">
    <div id="left">
          Select Country: <select id="country" name="country">
            <option value="germany">Germany</option>
            <option value="england">England</option>
          </select>
          <input type="button" value="Run Query" onClick="load()"></input>
    </div> 

   <div id="right">
      <div id="myDiv"></div>  
   </div>  
 </div>
```

---

test.php

```
 <?php
      $name=$_GET['country'];
      if($name=="England")
      {
       echo "Works"; 
      }
      else
      {
      echo "doesnt Work"; 
      }
 ?>
 ?>
```

Comment: Whats the problem? Also `$("#country").val()` will work fine.

Comment: "_There is some kind of problem with this code._" Saying "it doesn't work" isn't good enough. What should happen, what happens instead, and what debugging have you done and what has it told you?

Comment: It wouldnt echo anything, that's the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only issue I see is that in your PHP you have

```
if($name=="England")
```

But in your html you have

```
<option value="england">England</option>
```

It is sending over "england".  `"england"` != `"England"`.

Also, I would just do

```
$("#country").val()
```

instead of

```
$("#country option:selected").val()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 errors in your code :

```
 data: { country: $("#country option:selected").val()}
```

should be  $("#country").val()

and

```
if($name=="England")
```

shoudl be "england"

So Here is the right code :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function load()
{

  $.ajax({
  type:"GET",
  url: "test.php",
  data: {     country: $("#country").val()    }
  }).done(function(msg){
   $("#right #myDiv").html(msg);
  });

 }

 </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="main">
<div id="left">
      Select Country: <select id="country" name="country">
        <option value="germany">Germany</option>
        <option value="england">England</option>
      </select>
      <input type="button" value="Run Query" onClick="load()"></input>
</div>
```

And for the test.php :

```
 <?php
  $name=$_GET['country'];
  if($name=="england")
  {
   echo "Works"; 
  }
  else
  {
  echo "doesnt Work"; 
  }
 ?>
```

EDIT : It's pretty straight forward for me, but : be sure you call your page via your web server. The url in your browser should be :

```
http://localhost/whatever/page.html
```

and not (if from your hard drive) :

```
file://c:/whatever/page.html
```

Comment: what did you tried ? if you choose 'England' in the dropdown, it's write "Works" and if you chosse germany, it write's "doesn't work". So what's the problem ?

Comment: hhhmmm, are you sure you're using your web server and not your hard drive to open your html page ???

Answer (score 0):

if you mean too get work message from php file replace `England` with `england`, because php is case sensitive.

Comment: did you remove the extra php end tag in php file?